# Self Hosted RaspberryPi Web Server Not Displaying Background Image

Tags: html, css, web, webserver

I just set up a LAMP server on my raspberrypi and it is pretty cool. I set up a FTP server to send the webpage files to the Pi. I have a very basic form of the final webpage done and I sent it to my Pi over ftp and the 2 images, html file, and css file all transfer successfully but once I open my Pi in my browser (with 192.168.1.9) all I see is my title image and text. I don't see the background image I set. I tried both with inline style to set the background and with external but both don't work. My background image is 2.3MB and is 2560x1600 and it's css is:

```
#main {
background-image:url(background.png);
background-size: cover;
position:float;
}
```

I can open the webpage through the file directly but it doesn't work through the server. I don't know why the background image would just not display. I have tried reuploading the webpage files a few times but it hasn't changed.

Comment: Can you access the image on the server directly – does it load? (like: http://192.168.1.19/background.png)

Answer (score 0):

The file name of the image, including the extension, as quoted in the HTML, must be the same case as the file itself actually has. I found this out after moving from WAMP to Apache on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.